# Multiple theorem titles

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems

I want to display 2 titles of theorem and but only want to automatically refer one title of them

This is my code, it automatically refer the *whole* title

```latex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsthm,hyperref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[]

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Foo, or Bar]
\label{an example}
Mike is a human
\end{theorem}

By \nameref{example}, ...

\end{document}
```

[image]

I hope that the result can be like the following, it only refer a part of it, which I generated it manually. Besides ,and most importantly, I wish that if I change the "Foo" to "Baz", it can *automatically* change the title in referrence

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Where have you defined "Baz"?

Comment: @Peter Sorry, I am not good at English and this may cause your misunderstanding. I was meant to express that suppose I replace the "Foo" with "Baz" in the `\begin{theorem}[Foo, or Bar]`, the reference after it will change accordingly

Comment: @Mensch Thanks for making me feel welcome

Comment: Note that in OpTeX, we have `\ref[label]` command which allows alternative syntax `\ref[label]{text}`. When it is used, then `\ref` doesn't print a section/theorem number but prints the `text`. So, your task can be simply solved by `\ref[label]{Foo}`. Is something similar available in LaTeX too?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a command that behaves differently when typesetting the theorem title or when processing `\nameref`.

We just need to teach `\nameref` to use a different meaning for `\alt`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsthm,hyperref}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\NewDocumentCommand{\alt}{m}{#1}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\T@nameref}{\@gobble}{\@gobble\let\alt\@gobble}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Foo\alt{, or Bar}]
\label{example}
Mike is a human
\end{theorem}

By \nameref{example}, ...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But it seems not working, it still refer the *whole* theorem title

Comment: @HsiL It doesn't in my example.